# Obtendo resposta do WebService com Ksoap

Tags: java, android

Tenho um Web service que retorna estes dados:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <LISTACLIENTESRESPONSE xmlns="http://localhost:8093/">
         <LISTACLIENTESRESULT>
            <ACLIENTE>
               <STCLIENTE>
                  <CCODIGO>000001</CCODIGO>
                  <CRAZAO>PEDRO DA SILVA</CRAZAO>
                  <CMUNICIPIO>SAO PAULO</CMUNICIPIO>
                  <CVENDEDOR>JOAO</CVENDEDOR>
               </STCLIENTE>
               <STCLIENTE>
                  <CCODIGO>000002</CCODIGO>
                  <CRAZAO>JOSE</CRAZAO>
                  <CMUNICIPIO>SAO PAULO</CMUNICIPIO>
                  <CVENDEDOR>PAULO</CVENDEDOR>
               </STCLIENTE>
               <STCLIENTE>
                  <CCODIGO>000003</CCODIGO>
                  <CRAZAO>LETICIA</CRAZAO>
                  <CMUNICIPIO>SAO PAULO</CMUNICIPIO>
                  <CVENDEDOR>PEDRO</CVENDEDOR>
               </STCLIENTE>
            </ACLIENTE>
            <CMENSAGEM>3 Clientes Localizados</CMENSAGEM>
         </LISTACLIENTESRESULT>
      </LISTACLIENTESRESPONSE>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

No meu projeto do Android studio, consigo conectar e enviar os dados para WS mas não estou entendendo como recuperar os dados fornecidos pelo WS.

```
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarClientes);//Metodo esta correto

HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    SoapObject soapObject = 
    (SoapObject)resposta.getProperty("ACLIENTE");
    for(int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        soapObject.getProperty(1).toString());
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setCodigo(soapObject.getProperty("CCODIGO").toString());                
        cliente.setRazao(soapObject.getProperty("CRAZAO").toString());
        cliente.setMun(soapObject.getProperty("CMUNICIPIO").toString());
        listaClientes.add(cliente);
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    return listaClientes;
}
```

Como eu faço para recuperar esses dados? O retorno é um array de clientes e uma mensagem.

Executei este código:

```
SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); 
String clientes = envelope.getResponse().toString(); 
Log.i("CLIENTE",clientes);
```

O retorno no Log foi esse: anyType{ACLIENTE=anyType {STCLIENTE=anyType{CCODIGO=000819; CMUNICIPIO=SAO PAULO; CRAZAO=CLIENTE; CVENDEDOR=FIR1; };STCLIENTE=anyType{CCODIGO=001951; CMUNICIPIO=SANTOS;CRAZAO=CLIENTE 2; CVENDEDOR=FIR2; };}CMENSAGEM=2 Clientes Localizados.

Retornou todos os dados do Web Service.

Comment: Veja se `String clientes = envelope.getResponse().toString();` ajuda você. Isso deve converter o array contido no response em `String`, que então você vai manipular para preencher seu objeto `Cliente`. Se funcionar, avise e eu crio uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Como manipulo esta string para obter as informações separadas?

Comment: Uma pergunta: no seu código original, você chegar a receber como resposta esse XML que você colocou na pergunta? Se sim, é só questão de você usar um _parser_ de XML, que vai mapear cada cliente do XML para uma classe `Cliente` que você pode criar com as propriedades trazidas no XML. Nem precisaria converter para `String`.

Comment: O retorno voltou conforme postei acima. No programa SopUI o retorno aparece como código XML com as tags entre <>. Mas na string as tags estão entre {}. Mas este retorno é composto da seguinte estrutura: No primeiro nível tenho duas tags:  TAG CMENSAGEM (que é uma string) e a TAG ACLIENTE (que é um array de clientes). Para TAG ACLIENTE, existe o nível 2 que é a tag STCLIENTE(que são os clientes do array)  e dentro desta tag, tem as Tags: CCODIGO; CMUNICIPIO, CRAZAO e  CVENDEDOR (que são as informações de cada cliente. Nesta estrutura posso utilizar o parse de XML? Coo fazer?

Comment: Isso aqui vai lhe ajudar: [https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Tentei resolver pelo Parse mas não funcionou, pois quando passo o Objeto Ksoap para string, ele bagunça todo o código XML, colocando colchetes e removendo algumas tags.

Usei o próprio Ksoap para resolver.

```
     HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {

        http.call(METODOLISTA,envelope);
        SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        String mensagem = resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("CMENSAGEM").toString();
        SoapObject respostaClientes = (SoapObject) resposta.getProperty("ACLIENTE");

        for(int x = 0; x < respostaClientes.getPropertyCount(); x++) 
       {
            SoapObject clienteOb = (SoapObject) respostaClientes.getProperty(x);
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.setCodigo(clienteOb.getPrimitiveProperty("CCODIGO").toString());
            cliente.setRazao(clienteOb.getPrimitiveProperty("CRAZAO").toString());
    cliente.setMunicipio(clienteOb.getPrimitiveProperty("CMUNICIPIO").toString());
            cliente.setVendedor(clienteOb.getPrimitiveProperty("CVENDEDOR").toString());
            listaClientes.add(cliente);
       }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
           return listaClientes;
        }
```

A linha - SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse() retornou o XML inteiro.

Como a tag "CMENSAGEM" está no primeiro nível, consigo recupera-la com o comando:

String mensagem = resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("CMENSAGEM").toString();

Dai veio o pulo do gato, a Tag "ACLIENTE" é um array de Tags "STCLIENTE".
Com o comando abaixo - respostaClientes - recebeu o XML a partir da Tag "ACLIENTE"

SoapObject respostaClientes = (SoapObject) resposta.getProperty("ACLIENTE");

Dai foi só percorrer o objeto respostaCliente e ir capturando os dados
Funcionou........